# Wrapping multiple asynchronous calls into syncronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript, promise, deferred

let's say I have a function like this

```
getAllEpisodes = (show)->
   dfrd = new Deferred()
   eps = []
   for s of show.seasons
      api.getMeAllEpisodes(s.id).done (episodes)->
         eps = eps.concat(episodes)

   return dfrd.promise()
```

so when should I resolve the `dfrd`? Can't do that right after the for loop, right?
Also It makes it difficult without knowing exact number of episodes beforehand (without making api calls)

Comment: This is why promises have an `all()` method.

Comment: unfortunately the implementation of Deferred I'm using doesn't have `all()`. I'm using simplified version of `Deferred`. Any other implementation of promises not compatible with apple tv, for which I'm writing this app

Comment: You can write your own `all()` method by counting how many child promises have been fulfilled, then fulfilling the returned promise when all of them are.  (you'll also need to decide how to handle failures)

Comment: but as I said, there's no way to find out number of episodes without calling api

Comment: @Agzam: But you know how many promises you're waiting on.

Comment: "This is why promises have an all() method." No. To clarify, **promise libs** (may) have an `.all()` method, which accepts promises as its parameters.